# permision denied error ubuntu update with sudo

Tags: apt, sudo

Running the below command throws the Permission denied error in **Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS**

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and the error is

```
Get:16 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [149 kB]
Get:17 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [95.6 kB]
Get:18 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [387 kB]
Get:19 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [229 kB]
Get:20 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [181 kB]
Get:21 http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [117 kB]
Ign http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US         
Ign http://az1.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US     
Fetched 9,268 kB in 25s (370 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I'm following step as mentioned in juno installation of [openstack](http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html) guide

Answer (score 6):

You need to run both commands with `sudo`. You're running `sudo apt-get update` but then run `apt-get dist-upgrade` with no `sudo`. Try this instead:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```