# Can't install Git in kali Linux!

Tags: kali-linux, git

I am a new kali Linux user and after installing kali linux i tried to install git but i am getting a message where it says

```
E: Could not open lock file/var/lib/dpkg/lock -fronted -open (13: permission denied )
E: are you root ?
```

The command I have used :

```
apt install git
```

Can any one help me to overcome the problem ?

Comment: Were you root when you ran it? I don't see a `sudo`, but perhaps you were logged in as root?

Comment: Kali is meant for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me), not for development. So the simplest approach is to use some other distro (e.g. a Debian based one, Kali is Debian based). Then everything will work out of the box, the package manager will work out of the box, and you'll have all the hacking tools Kali has, but none of the headaches. Kali is not "what all the hackers" use, no matter what you read on some forums.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176152/117549 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515874/117549?

Comment: Are you new to Gnu/Linux if so then kali is not for you. Install Debian.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor dude i am interested in Cyber security ! shouldn't i try to learn how to operate kali? I guess people uses kali for that ....

Comment: If you are interested in cyber security, then start with Debian Gnu/Linux. Learn command-line, then some security tools: wireshark, zenmap, gufw, nftables, .... (most if not all of kali's tools are in Debian). Only then look at kali. It is better to learn the basics, and most of the rest on a stable, easy to use, system.

Comment: @schl...r to be honest people here give Kali too much credit saying it's "for experts". Sure it has some penetration testing tools, but based on the questions I see here it is too often broken right after a clean install... It takes a Linux expert to *fix* it.  If you want to learn penetration testing it might be easier to figure out how to install the tools on Debian first and leave Kali for a time whe you won't mind beating yourself up with a (frequently) broken distribution.  Comments here are of course my own opinion.

Comment: @PhilipCouling legit comment ! Wonderful ! Yeah i will be switching to debian  ! Mind to share any link that helps noob ?

Comment: @PhilipCouling will there be any problem if i install it in virtual box ? Will i able to acess through all the functions ?

Comment: Feel free. Kali should work as well in a VM as it does on bare metal.  I've seen a number of people actively suggest running it in a VM.

Comment: @PhilipCouling i was talking about debian !

Comment: @Schl....r Debian installs are really straight forward. I've run them on virtualbox for a while.  You might need to double check you have enough video ram configured if you get a black or frozen screen but besides that it runs just fine.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are new to Linux.

I may catch some heat for answering this, but the error message is telling you that you are not running the command with root permissions (similar to "Run as Administrator" in Windows).

In order for you to run commands with root permissions you must add the command `sudo` to the beginning of your command string. So what you need to run is `sudo apt install git`. This goes for any Debian/Ubuntu variant including Debian, Ubuntu, Kali Linux, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, PopOS, Mint, and whichever other ones I may be missing.

The comments above are helpful so please see the posts that are linked there.

Comment: So nice of you ! Yeah i am new to Linux ! Not familiar with it but trying my best to learn ! Is it a wrong decision that i have started learning linux with the kali ?

Comment: Do you have any books as a suggestion where i can catch up things easily and can apply it practically ?

Comment: Not all Debian forks come with `sudo` out of the box.  Debian itself didn't for some years, I haven't installed recently.  There is another command `su` that lets you login as root.  But you need to know root's password. With sudo you use your own password.

Comment: @Schl....r Not a huge deal to start with Kali but I recommend starting with Ubuntu. I only recommend this because of the previous comments on your post. There are tons of Youtube video's out there that explain how to navigate your way around the system for the quickest start. I only have books for Red Hat variants.

Answer (score -1):

See, that's nice.. you used the correct command, but you're not using it as super user...
so first run..

-> sudo su

then you have to enter your password,

and after getting access as super user..

- apt-get install git

Comment: There is never a good reason to use `sudo su`. At best just use `sudo`, and if that doesn't work use `sudo -s`. Or best of all, merge the commands `sudo apt-get install git`.

Answer (score -1):

I use this for Kali Linux:

```
sudo -i
```